# Why is there unexpected space at the beginning of a paragraph in an answer?

Tags: bug, mathjax, editing, markdown-preview

In @GabeK's nice [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/363464) to @JonBannon's question [Each mathematician has only a few tricks](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/363226/each-mathematician-has-only-a-few-tricks), there is unexpected space at the beginning of the third paragraph:

[image: @GabeK's answer with spurious space]

My first thought was that there might be a macro definition or something at the beginning of the third paragraph, so I opened up the edit window to see.  Not only is there nothing obvious in the source to cause this extra space, but also it goes away when editing:

[image: @GabeK's answer while editing]

I see this on both Firefox and Safari, using the HTML-CSS renderer.  Why?

Comment: The line immediately preceding "The named..." has a single space in it.  Apparently, this causes this space to be rendered.  The editor may be using the newer or different Markdown renderer, for example, which is why you cannot see this space during editing.

Comment: I will just add that the character mentioned in the previous comment seems to be [Non-breaking space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space). In case it is useful, you might check what you get for that post [from the Posts table](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1435952/title-body-and-tags-of-the-given-post?list=363464) and [from the PostHistory table](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1616586/past-bodies-of-the-given-post?id=363464).

Comment: Thanks, @DmitriPavlov!  [That](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/5401/why-is-there-unexpected-space-at-the-beginning-of-a-paragraph-in-an-answer#comment27506_5401) seems to be an answer, so, if you'd post it, then I'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: Thanks, @MartinSleziak!  I'm not sure how to use the Posts table and the PostHistory table.  When I click the links you have supplied, I see one row of a table returned from a query, including the partial rendered HTML of the post, and clicking on the link takes me to the post.  How should I extract more information (e.g., the full rendered HTML)?

Comment: @LSpice You can simply ignore those queries if they are of no use for you. In any case, I left [a few short messages in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/19138/2022/7/14) - feel free to ping me there if some additional explanation could help.

Comment: @MartinSleziak, [thanks](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/5401/why-is-there-unexpected-space-at-the-beginning-of-a-paragraph-in-an-answer#comment27511_5401)!  I in no way meant to imply that the queries weren't useful, only that I didn't know how to use them, but your [chat messages](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/19138/2022/7/14) addressed that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line immediately preceding "The named..." has a single non-breaking space in it, which is preserved in the output.

The editor may be using a differently configured Markdown renderer, for example, which is why you cannot see this space during editing.

Depending on your point of view, this could be considered a bug in the editor and/or the Markdown parser.